# Problem in calculating the confidence interval (Fleiss Kappa) in SPSS

Tags: confidence-interval, spss

I'm calculating the Fleiss Kappa for inter-rater and intra-rater reliability. I have 3 raters and they rated 10 types of forests as 'tropical', 'temperate' or 'boreal'. This is done twice with the same 3 raters and same 10 forests, once in January and once in February.

I'm using SPSS > Analyze > Scale > Reliability analysis > [image]

I've gotten the inter-rater reliability for Jan and Feb. And the intra-rater reliability for Rater 1, 2 and 3. But now I'm trying to combine all the data.

I figured I could just calculate the mean kappa of the inter-rater reliability for Jan and Feb, and the mean kappa of Rater 1, 2 and 3. But I'm not sure how to get the 95% confidence interval if I were to do this.

Sorry I do not have any background in statistics at all. If I'm using SPSS wrongly or if calculating the mean kappa like this is wrong I would greatly appreciate the feedback.